# Same string results in different MD5 Hash

Tags: rest, go, md5

Its pretty straightforward. The passes don't match. I can't find why.

The hashing function

```
package utils
var hasher = md5.New()

func GetMD5Hash(text string) string {

    fmt.Println(">> ", text, "<<")
    hasher.Write([]byte(text))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
}
`
```

I make 1st restful call to create a user (register) calls this method.

```
func CreateUser(id bson.ObjectId, email string, password string) bool {
    var user User
    user.ID = id
    user.Email = email
    user.Password = utils.GetMD5Hash(password)

    // fmt.Println("In Create User:", password, user.Password)

    err := userCollection.Insert(&user)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while CreateUser")
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Now I make 2nd restful call to authenticate (login)

The Authenticate User Method

```
func AuthenticateUser(email string, password string) bool {
    user := GetUserByEmail(email)

    var u User

    u.Password = utils.GetMD5Hash(password)
    fmt.Println("In Authenticate:", password, u.Password)
    fmt.Println(u.Password, user.Password)

    if u.Password == user.Password {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

PASSWORDS DONT MATCH.

Results:

```
>>  pass <<
In Authenticate: pass 1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72
1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72 1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72
>>  pass <<
{ObjectIdHex("5ae3746e1b2a612417149bca") []}
>>  pass <<
In Authenticate: pass dbe4a8e3a3b93ed3101bace4bc19fc70
dbe4a8e3a3b93ed3101bace4bc19fc70 078bbb4bf0f7117fb131ec45f15b5b87
>>  pass <<
{ObjectIdHex("5ae374a31b2a612417149bcb") []}
>>  pass <<
In Authenticate: pass c4e6ffe7c63bb65e68521293416c96a2
c4e6ffe7c63bb65e68521293416c96a2 1bdfd5f0b03c0d80557384602303c690
>>  pass <<
In Authenticate: pass c6d90629ad5c6b8edbe479340d5bed6b
c6d90629ad5c6b8edbe479340d5bed6b 1bdfd5f0b03c0d80557384602303c690
>>  pass <<
In Authenticate: pass 5b54f4793a13c985b4f4275980542496
5b54f4793a13c985b4f4275980542496 1bdfd5f0b03c0d80557384602303c690
```

If it is not clear, I am literally making the same request repeatedly and every time results in a new MD5Hash.
Also, both the register and login process uses the same UI, same text boxes different buttons.

Insights. Please.

Comment: Can you simplify your example to show only the behavior that's concerning you? If you're worried about MD5 hashing, there's no need for any REST API calls in your sample.

Comment: If you create a [mcve], you can easily see what's happening: https://play.golang.org/p/JdtoRiy3QG9.  Unrelated, storing passwords as an md5 hash is about the least secure way you could possibly do it.

Comment: Your solution may also have a data race if `GetMD5Hash()` is called from multiple goroutines (e.g. from HTTP handlers), because you don't synchronize access to your global hasher. Just use the [`md5.Sum()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/#Sum) _function_ without creating a hasher.

Comment: @JimB Thank you very much. That is very good advice. Next time I'll follow it. Also, I know Md5 isn't the optimal way of storing a password, heard bcrpyt is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though you are writing over and over to the same (package level variable) `hasher`, so that at first it contains `'pass'`, then `'passpass'`, then `'passpasspass'` (as []byte of course) so the result changes because the underlying bytes are changing. Try putting in the `var hasher = md5.New()` inside the `GetMD5Hash` function.

Comment: and for more idiomatic go, I would likely write it as ```hasher := md5.New()``` inside the function.

Comment: Or if allocations were a concern, simply calling `hasher.Reset()` (though that isn't safe for concurrent access)